# Where does this rebase come from?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-pull, git-stash

I recently created a new branch locally, published it to remote and it received an update from a colleague.
While I do have changes in my repository, none of them are on files that were modified.
I therefore expected that a `git pull` would work as implied by the message from `git status`:

```
$ git status
On branch XXX
Your branch is behind 'origin/XXX' by 2 commits, and can be fast-forwarded.
  (use "git pull" to update your local branch)

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
    modified:   ...
```

However pulling results in an error message implying that there is a rebase in progress:

```
$ git pull
error: cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
error: please commit or stash them.
```

I don't know where this might have come from as I never consciously did a rebase.
Also, strangely:

```
$ git rebase --continue
fatal: No rebase in progress?
```

I can pull when stashing my changes and popping them afterwards without a problem, and am aware of the autostash option, but I would like to understand what is going on here.

Where did the rebase come from?
Why do git pull and git rebase appear to disagree whether there is a rebase?
How can I clean up this mess?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Where did the rebase come from?

As [@coyotte508 pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69264939/26396), you have likely configured `git pull` to do a rebase instead of a merge by setting the [`pull.rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullrebase) option in your Git config file (either globally or in the current repo).

> Why do git pull and git rebase appear to disagree whether there is a rebase?

They don't. `git pull` simply refused to do the rebase because you have uncommitted changes in your working directory. By the time `git pull` exits, there's no rebase in progress.

> How can I clean up this mess?

You can either commit or stash your changes prior to doing `git pull` (the [`rebase.autostash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-rebaseautoStash) option that you mentioned will do the latter for you automatically). Alternatively, you could set [`pull.rebase`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-pullrebase) to `false` and have `git pull` do a regular merge, but [I wouldn't recommend it](http://megakemp.com/2019/03/20/the-case-for-pull-rebase/).

Answer (score 1):

You probably have rebase automatically enabled when pulling. Try

```
git config pull.rebase
git config --global pull.rebase
```

See if either is `true`. If that's the case, you can do:

```
git config pull.rebase false
git config --global pull.rebase false
```

(or use `--unset`)